# How I can set a specific cell from excel in python?

Tags: python, matrix, openpyxl, adjacency-matrix

I'm doing a function with python where I have to create a matrix in Excel, but for that I need to know how I can manipulate some keyboard request to specific excel cells positions in it to create this matrix with some values in this cells.

The code that I have right now it is here:

```
import sys
import openpyxl as opxl


def crear_menu():
  menu=int(input("Elija una opción \n 1.Crear parámetros \n 
  2.Aplicar Dijkstra \n 3.Aplicar Kruskal \n 4.Salir"))
  if menu == 1:
      min_nodos()
  elif menu == 2:
      dijkstra()
  elif menu == 3:
      kruskal()
  elif menu == 4:
      sys.exit()
  else:
      print("\n ERROR: Elija una opción válida.")
      crear_menu()

def crear_matriz_adyacente2(cant_nodos):
    lista_nodos = []
    lista_matriz = []
    lista_filas = []
    lista_columnas = []
    libro = opxl.Workbook()
    pagina = libro.active
    pagina.title = "matriz_de_adyacencia"
    i = 0
    while(i < cant_nodos):
        num = str(i+1)
        nodo = str(input("Ingresar nombre del nodo " + num + ":"))
        if nodo not in lista_nodos:
            lista_nodos.append(nodo)
            pagina.cell(row = i+2, column = 1, value = nodo)
            pagina.cell(row = 1, column = i+2, value = nodo)
            i += 1
        elif(nodo < 0):
            print("ERROR: Nodo no valido")
        else:
            print("Error: Nodo existente. \n Ingrese otro nombre: ")
    

    
 
    libro.save("matriz_de_adyacencia.xlsx")

def min_nodos():
    cant_nodos = int(input("Elija la cantidad de nodos a utilizar 
(mínimo 6):"))
    while(cant_nodos < 6):
        print("ERROR: Elija mínimo 6 nodos y que sea entero positivo.")
        cant_nodos = int(input("Elija la cantidad de nodos a utilizar (mínimo 6):"))
    else:
        crear_matriz_adyacente(cant_nodos)
```

Here in the red box I'm trying to do the matrix, but I don't know the best way to import a specific excel cell. I mean, I don't know if with this I'm referring to A2.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [You shouldn't upload pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please edit your question to include formatted code, preferably as a [mcve] to make it easier to help you.

Comment: If `opxl` is [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), then the [documentation describes how to access specific cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and help. The documentation helps me a lot!.

Comment: Glad the link to the documentation was helpful. You [can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future folks who come across your question.